# How can I all a JS function in a browser console if the JS function is included in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/script.js"></script>
```

JQuery function here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   function rnmtn(){
      console.log("red");
   }
});
```

How can I call `rnmtn();` in the console without it returning `undefined` - the script is not linked to an html object - I need it to function on its own.

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready(function()...` Just declare function rnmtn right away         `function rnmtn()
        {
            console.log("red");
        }`

Comment: @Learn How To Be Transparent - Thanks :) That worked.

Comment: You said 
> the script is not linked to an html object - I need it to function on its own.
 
So, as everyone has said, you should just take it out of the `$(document).ready` block if it doesn't necessarily have to wait for the page to finish loading. Putting it in the ready block makes it a closure inaccessible to the window object (which is the scope the console code executes from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your function

```
function rnmtn(){
  console.log("red");
}
```

and call it in console by typing

```
rnmtn()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the function accessible in the window scope,

such like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.rnmtn = function rnmtn(){
      console.log("red");
   }
});
```

Comment: What? Just remove **`$(document).ready()`**. It's pointless to define a function inside **`$(document).ready()`** when you actually want it to be accessible  in the global scope.

Comment: yes, I see @einScotchFitch declare it inside $(document).ready(), so I guess it has some meaning for him to do it. If not, just remove $(document).ready() will be more clear.

Comment: Since @einScotchFitch wants ther function be available from the global scope, it shouldn't have any meaning for them declaring it inside **`$(document).ready()`**. Not your fault though.